# Лаг при Instantiate

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда делаю так:

```
Instantiate(Effects, transform.position, Effects.transform.rotation).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
```

Происходит лаг - задержка не на долго, после чего появляется эффект.

После повторных действий, задержки уже нет, как только останавливаю сцену и запускаю снова, опять также история возникает.

С чем это может быть связано?
Уж больно напрягает этот глюк.
Эффект создается из префаба.

Когда я убираю этот код лагов нет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не "Глюк". Эта работа с памятью. Мобилки особенно чувствительны из-за чего и происходят статеры. И не только при выделении памяти на новый объект, но и на выгрузки тоже. У unity и без того паршивый garbage collector с постоянными пунктуации нагрузки памяти. По возможности нужно оптимизировать так, что-бы одни и те-же объекты эффектов, пуль и т.д. использовались многократно и были предзагруженные.

Comment: А как правильно сделать предзагрузку? Можно примерчик?

Comment: @Vendor так как написал я в своем ответе) Просто прийдется переносить его еще в ракету и сделать сдвиг в координатах, например.

Comment: `Instantiate` и `gameObject.SetActive(false)` до момента пока объект тебе не понадобится, а отыграв своё снова `SetActive(false)`. И пишишь некий менеджер, который заведует списками этих объектов. И раздражающие микро статеры исчезнуть.

Comment: Все летает, сделал просто загрузку, и плей, а после удалил и все работает нормально на всех устройствах. Просто на первой сцене где лоадинг, перекинул лоадинг и когда все объекты грузанулись и отработали там 0.1 секунда, удаляется загрузчик

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй создать партикл систем при создании сцены( start() ) и присвоить его в переменную в самом скрипте.

А в нужном месте уже запускать play() даной системы частиц.

Comment: Он должен появляться только при попадании ракетой например куда-то. Я заметил это только на более сложных эффектах почемуто так происходит.

Comment: значит создавай вместе с ракетой. Или создавай 1 инстанс и перенось его в ракету по надобности.